# How do I figure out the equation of a function from just the $x$ and $y$ values

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

One problem on my latest test that stumped me is a question like this:

> $t$ (minutes): 0, 4, 9, 15, 20
>   $W(t)$ (°F): 55.0, 57.1, 61.8, 67.9, 71.0
>
> (a) Use the data above to estimate the derivative of $W$ at time $t=12$, $W'(12)$. The function may not necessarily be linear.

In order to move on with the problem with derivatives, I need to figure out how to find out the function from just the $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: You can try a quartic equation and solve for the coefficients. Anything here will be interpolation though.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest answer (lying entirely within pre-university mathematics), this is just a matter of finding which interval (between samples) $t=12$ lies in. Here it lies between $t=9$ and $t=15$, where $W(t)=61.8$ and $W(t)=67.9$ respectively, so
$$W'(12)\approx\frac{67.9-61.8}{15-9}=1.017$$

Comment: The answer to this is not unique and probably should be mentioned. For example you can use other two points to approximate the derivative. Interpolation can also be done and then derivative can be calculated from that.

Comment: @Gregory An estimate was asked for... but nevertheless included your points.

Comment: I think this is a fine answer.  There are other ways to evaluate the derivative, fitting a higher order polynomial through some of the points, but if you don't know anything about the source of the numbers assuming a linear function between the neighboring points is quite reasonable and less sensitive to measurement errors than higher order fitting.  I would plot the data and see if I found any inspiration, like that it looked quadratic.  Failing that, I would follow this approach.

Comment: What is interesting to notice is that the data are very nicely fitted using a cubic polynomial. Compouting the derivative at $t=12$ would lead to $W'(12)=1.039$. No need to do such a curve fit; Parcly Taxel's simple solution is more than enough.